# Simple Generating Function Not Working the Way I Interpret it?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions, word-problem

> Suppose we let A be all sequences of zeros and ones, with generating function $F (z) = 1/(1 − 2z)$.

> Now suppose we can attach a single or double prime to each $0$ or $1$, giving $0′$ or $0′′$ or $1′$ or $1′′$, and we want a generating function for the number of distinct primed bit-strings with $n$ attached primes.

> The set { $’$, $’’$} has generating function $G(z) = z + z^2$ so the composite set has generating function $$F (G(z)) = 1/(1 − 2(z + z^2 ))= 1/(1 − 2z − 2z^2 )$$

In this, when I extract the coefficient of $z^2$, I get $6$, but when I hand count there should be $12$. I got $6$ from $1 + 2(z + z^2 )+ 4(z + z^2 )^2$, and the $12$ comes from each option as a starter having two options for a secondary when $n = 2$.

I’m confused on why I’m getting $6$, because when I self count, I get pairs $(0,0’’), (0,1’’), (1,1’’), (1,0’’), (0’ ,0’), (0’ ,1’), (1’ ,1), (1’ ,0), (0’’ ,0), (0’’ ,1), (1’’ ,1), (1’’ ,0)$ which is $12$

I might be misinterpreting what the n is supposed to be? I thought it was supposed to be equal to the weight of the term so $z^2$ would have $n=2$?

Or I am misinterpreting what this generating function is counting?

Comment: The setup is pretty vaguely worded, but it means each bit has a prime, i.e. there are no bits without primes. So, $(0', 0')$ is fine and so is $(1'')$, but $(1', 0)$ is not.

Comment: If a bit were allowed to have no primes, $G(z)$ would be $1+z+z^2$.

Comment: I get it now. It works this way because for F(G(z)) the z is represents the number of primes so the since the thing being plugged into F is what matters aka the string length does not have to be the same as the number of primes

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, though then the problem would break badly since there would be infinitely many strings of each sort. The generating function cries if you try to do this too, e.g. the $z^2$ coefficient of $1/(1-2(1+z+z^2))$ is $-2$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson: Oh, absolutely. And that, if nothing else, should make it clear how the problem is to be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G(z)$ isn't the GF for $\{',''\}$ because they aren't numbers or a sequence.

$G(z)=z+z^2$ is the GF for $a_1=1, a_2=1, a_n=0, n\ge2$.

Your GF is [A002605](https://oeis.org/A002605), $a_n = 2(a_{n-1} + a_{n-2})$.

Comment: why is my GF the thing at the bottom? Right the one for $1/(1-x)$ is $T(z) = (1/2)(T(z-1)+T(z-2))

Comment: If you expand it, you get $1+2z+6z^2+16z^3+44z^4+\dots$, as in A002605, and as given by the recurrence. Compare with the GF for the Fibonacci numbers [A000045](https://oeis.org/A000045), and you can begin to see how GF's work.